# How do I use SQL UPDATE in Xojo to remove leading quotes

Tags: sqlite, realbasic, xojo

I have an SQLite database attached to a Xojo project. I need to strip off the first character, IF it is a quote mark. Here is what I tried:

```
  t=Chr(34)+"%"  // this holds the Quote mark and the wild card  
  S="db.SQLExecute UPDATE "+ CurrentTableName + " SET " + Feilder +" = SUBSTRING("+Feilder+", 2, LEN("+Feilder+")) "
  S=S+"WHERE "+Feilder+" LIKE "+t
  db.SQLExecute S
```

I am getting a syntax error even without the WHERE clause. `CurrentTableName` holds the table name, `Feilder` holds the field (or column) being evaluated.

In SQLite, here is what I am trying to do:

```
UPDATE Table SET Myfield = SUBSTRING(Myfield, 2, LEN(MyField))
WHERE MyFiled LIKE "%
```

Thanks, Eric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea! Fixed it. Thanks

My OLD code had S="db.SQLExecute UPDATE ...
Later I execute db.SQLExecure S

As you see from below, one change and ... it works. The S= now starts with the UPDATE and not the execute command.

BTW, this code strips off the leading quote if it gets into a database field. And ONLY the leading quote.

```
  t=Chr(34)+"%"
  S="UPDATE "+ CurrentTableName + " SET " + Feilder +" = SUBSTR("+Feilder+", 2, LENGTH("+Feilder+")) "
  S=S+"WHERE "+Feilder+" LIKE '"+t+"'"

  db.SQLExecute S
```

Thanks Kyle for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The function for selecting a substring is subst(), rather than substring(). Also, you should put single quotes around the "%...('"%').

Comment: That did not fix the problem, but I will see if I can break this into parts and see where the issues lies. I am sure that your SUBST() part was a help. Thanks